# Linq Query Grouping Data table using two columns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I've got one question here. I'm a newbie so pardon with my terminologies, I am querying a data table wherein I need to group this data table according to date and their unique access code.

```
var tMainTable = (from System.Data.DataRow b in _tData.data_table.Rows
group b by b["ACCESS_CODE"] into bGroup
select new
{ bGroup });
```

in my current grouping above, I am grouping my data table according to access code. My data table is composed of 3 fields: DATE, ACCESS_CODE, COUNT. This is provided that I cant make my datatable `AsEnumerable()` type.

So this time, I want to add in its condition, which is grouping by date as well... is there such thing as:

```
var tMainTable = (from System.Data.DataRow b in _tData.data_table.Rows
**group b by b["ACCESS_CODE"] AND b["DATE"] into bGroup**
select new
{ bGroup });
```

Thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tMainTable = (from System.Data.DataRow b in _tData.data_table.Rows
group b by new { AccessCode = b["ACCESS_CODE"], Date = b["DATE"] } into bGroup
select new
{ bGroup });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an anonymous type for your grouping:

```
var codeDateGroups = _tData.data_table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new { 
        AccessCode = r.Field<string>("ACCESS_CODE"), 
        Date = r.Field<DateTime>("DATE") 
    });
```

You can access it via the `Key`:

```
foreach(var group in codeDateGroups)
    Console.WriteLine("Code=[{0}] Date=[{1}]" 
        , group.Key.AccessCode
        , group.Key.Date);
```

Comment: this .AsEnumerable() does not appear in my autocomplete... Perhaps it is not applicable I dunno why...

Comment: @Charmie: While the class holding the extensions is in the `System.Data` namespace, it's located in an assembly that isn't added to your project by default. Add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` to your project and it should be ok. [**Here's**](http://www.bilder-hochladen.net/files/k9jr-3-eccb.png) a screenshot.

Comment: @Charmie: Do you have added this to the top of the file: `using System.Data;` ? Btw, here's the method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx It exists since .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

```
var groups =  _tData.data_table.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(row=> new {row["ACCESS_CODE"],row["DATE"] });
```